# Why checkboxes don't work inside a form?

Tags: forms, angular

I have an objects array

```
pets = [{key: 'dog', isChecked: true}, {key: 'hamster', isChecked: false}, {key: 'cat', isChecked: false}];
```

and display it like checkboxes

```
<div *ngFor='let pet of pets'>
    <input type='checkbox'
     name='pets'
     value='{{pet}}'
     [(ngModel)]='pet.isChecked'
     (change)='check()'
    />
    {{pet.key}} - {{pet.isChecked}}
</div>
```

but as soon as I start putting it inside a form

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor='let pet of pets'>
        <input type='checkbox'
         name='pets'
         value='{{pet}}'
         [(ngModel)]='pet.isChecked'
         (change)='check()'
        />
        {{pet.key}} - {{pet.isChecked}}
    </div>
</form>
```

It stops displaying correctly.

How can I make this work with a form?

[Plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/28Ln0nwMtuCKuNgbdPTz?p=preview)

and

[Plunkr link with a form](https://plnkr.co/edit/4gHyoU62Q6PIsejEfpxl?p=preview)

Comment: what issue you started facing , please create a plnkr or jsfiddle for better understanding

Comment: @Viplock Updated the question.

Comment: `input.name` property has to be unique https://plnkr.co/edit/6qgA1wnJOWgZUP0BGBmb?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<form>
        <div *ngFor='let pet of pets'>
            <input type='checkbox'
               name='pets'
               id="pets{{getRandom()}}"
               [ngModel]="pet.isChecked"
               value='{{pet}}'
               (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); check();"/>
            {{pet.key}} - {{pet.isChecked}}
        </div>
    </form>
```

TS :

```
function getRandom() {
    return Math.random() * 1000;
}
```